# Blackboard SOAP web service php

Tags: php, web-services, soap, blackboard

I am using [this library](https://github.com/stedwards/Blackboard-Web-Services-PHP-Library) to do the development about blackboard web service.

I have successfully registered the proxy tool and make it available in the administrator panel.

The connection is built and function is able to be used. 
But When I call the saveColumns in Gradebook in Blackboard web service library,

```
$coursemember_detail = $blackboard->Gradebook("saveColumns",array('courseId'=>'_50_1','columnName'=>'testing'));
```

It returns

```
array(1) { ["@attributes"]=> array(1) { ["nil"]=> string(4) "true" } }
```

According to [blackboard api library SP13](http://library.blackboard.com/ref/af83996d-1815-4682-8b01-7fe376e9547f/index.htm), it should return the ids of the columns.

Anyone knows the answer? Or anyone knows what problem is that?
It will be great if you can provide me some advice and answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument for this call should consist of 2 attributes `courseId` and `columns`. In the `columns` attribute you will need to describe your column as it will be shown in grade center. I haven't tested an array of columns, but for a single column that you want to create your code could look like this:

```
$params = array();
$params['courseId'] = '_50_1';
$params['columns'] = array(
        'columnName' => 'testing',
        'possible' => "100.0",
        "scorable"=> "true",
        "showStatsToStudent"=> "true",
        "visible"=> "true",
        "visibleInBook"=> "true",
    );

$id = $blackboard->Gradebook( "saveColumns", $params );
```

If everything is ok you will get a newly-created column id in return like this: `_1326_1`