# Creating a grade center column with Blackboard SOAP web service using php

Tags: php, web-services, blackboard

I'm using the [Blackboard-Web-Services-PHP-Library](https://github.com/stedwards/Blackboard-Web-Services-PHP-Library), and when I make a call like the following (as per the example in a previous question here: [Blackboard SOAP web service php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30294472/blackboard-soap-web-service-php/31245756)), BB's web service creates one column for each key/value pair in the columns array, and returns an array of the new column ids. None of these new cols have any of the desired characteristics. Any suggestions?

```
$params = array();
$params['courseId'] = '_174_1';
$params['columns'] = array(
  'columnName' => 'testing',
  'possible' => "100.0",
  "scorable"=> "true",
  "showStatsToStudent"=> "true",
  "visible"=> "true",
   "visibleInBook"=> "true",
 );

$id = $blackboard->Gradebook( "saveColumns", $params );
```

The print_r($id) output:

```
Array
(
  [0] => _441_1
  [1] => _442_1
  [2] => _443_1
  [3] => _444_1
  [4] => _445_1
  [5] => _446_1
)
```

Comment: what version of Bb are you using? The code works with 9.1 Apr 2014. I'm not sure why it doesn't work for you, but I would try to call `getGradebookColumns` on any existing course with grade center set up, and try to examine the returned column object. Then I would call `saveColumns` with just one attribute (i.e. `columnName`, or whatever is easy to verify) to see if it works.

Comment: also, I would try to enclose your column definition in an array like this: `$params['columns'] = array( array(
  'columnName' => 'testing'
 ) );` to see if it makes any difference.